# Add space in after currency sign in magento

Tags: zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7

how to add space after currency sign in magento1.7.

I have changed the default currency to Bolivian Boliviano. its value is BOB.

In product listing page its displaying like VEB12.98 i need like VEB. 12.98

Answer (score 5):

As of 1.7, you can actually change/edit the currency symbol directly in the admin area:

System > Manage Currency > Symbols

Comment: In system there is no option called manage currency. there is only currency. it lists only installed currency list.

Comment: When you hover over system > 'manage currency' you should see two new options: rates and symbols.  If not then you are either not running 1.7.x or your user role does not have permission to the manage symbols option.

Answer (score 0):

Edit in the language file **lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml**
or
**lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en_US.xml** accordingly near the symbol ¤.

`<currencyFormat>
  <pattern>¤ #,##0.00;(¤ #,##0.00)</pattern>
</currencyFormat>`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Magento Community Version < 1.7, you may add the space by yourself.

```
$_price = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice());
```

Get the price html from the above code, and then you may use php function to insert the dot and space:

```
$_price = str_replace('VEB', 'VEB. ', $_price);
```

If you have already used Magento 1.7, answer from Drew Hunter may be helpful to you.

Comment: I down voted as the question clearly says magento 1.7.  An extra reason for my downvoting is that the solution is hacky as requires str_replace to be added to every template in the system that outputs a price